# To Execute Ajax requests in Sequence

Tags: javascript

Thanks for viewing my question. I am hopeful that you might help me go in the right direction.

**Problem:**
User sends a list of company name and server sends the corresponding logo back.
The restriction is that the logo needs to be placed left to right and then top to bottom.
The order should not change.

**Approach Followed:**
We are using an Array of Company Names appearing row wise -
Like:
[ [Companies_**Row1**] ,  [Companies_**Row2**],  [Companies_**Row3**] ]

Each [Companies_Row] has values like [‘Ford’, ‘BMW’, ‘Audi']
[[image: Car Array Looks Like This]

We expect the logos to appear in order, however presently we are getting them in random order.

---

Solution we are thinking is to iterate over the arrays and make use of Promises.
However we are struggling to implement this since last two days. Please help us resolve the same.

**Code Snippets:**

```
    // arrayOfCompanyNames - contains an Array of [Array of Company Names] appearing in a row. Please Refer Screenshot.

   // Function where we are traversing the company Name and making call
    function getCompanyLogos(arrayOfCompanyNames) {
      var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        resolve(1);
      });
      promise.then(function(){
        arrayOfCompanyNames.forEach(function(item) {
          item.forEach(function(value, index) {
            if(index == item.length - 1){
              // When a row is complete then move to the next row.
              promise = promise.then(LogoFetchPromis(value, true));
            } else {
              promise = promise.then(LogoFetchPromis(value));
            }
          });
        });
      });
    }



function LogoFetchPromis(carName, wrapNow){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      $.ajax({
          url: "/getLogo/" + carName,
          dataType: 'text'
        })
        .done(function(response) {
          resolve(response);
     // logos is the section where logos should appear
          $('.logos').append(response);
          if (wrapNow)
            $('.logos').append('<br>');
        })
        .fail(function(response) {
          reject(Error(response));
        });
    });
}
```

Please help us find a resolution for the same.

Comment: Can't you put some flag along with your request & response that says position of your logo over UI.

Comment: Each row needs to progress one after the another and then wrap at end of the row. Tracking position will make it very slow and performance will be huge impact, this in itself will make it synchronous

Comment: That's fine but you can at least place your logo from response on required position. i.e. if 1st logo of 2nd row comes first from async request put on that place only. keep 1st row empty till you get response from their request.

Comment: I don't think so. well, practically it's possible through async only. anyways good luck.

Comment: how are you getting img sources like src="someurl.net" or are you getting raw images?

Comment: I am getting raw images. Issue is with the execution of Ajax calls, how to chain them properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep it simple. One solution is first fetch all of your images by building an array of promises reproducing the structure of `arrayOfCompanyNames` then use `Promise.all()` to keep the order of the promises result. And then you can loop over the results array and show the logos (add error management as you need).

```
// arrayOfCompanyNames - contains an Array of [Array of Company Names] appearing in a row. Please Refer Screenshot.
var arrayOfCompanyNames;

// Function where we are traversing the company Name and making call
function getCompanyLogos(arrayOfCompanyNames) {
    // build an array of promises mirroring arrayOfCompanyNames
    var promises = [];
    arrayOfCompanyNames.forEach(function (subArray) {
        var subPromises = [];
        subArray.forEach(function (carName) {
            // $.ajax is a promise so you use it directly
            subPromises.push($.ajax({
                url: '/getLogo/' + carName,
                dataType: 'text'
            }));
        });
        promises.push(Promise.all(subPromises));
    });

    // show everything, results is nicely formatted so you know when to <br>
    return Promise.all(promises).then(function done(results) {
        // results look like [[row1], [row2], [row3]]
        results.forEach(function (row) {
            row.forEach(function (carLogo) {
                $('.logos').append(carLogo);
            });
            $('.logos').append('<br>');
        });
    })
}
```

The `Promise.all()` solution will introduce a delay, the logos will show at once when they're all fetched. They will be downloaded all at the same time so be careful if it's not your server you're requesting (almost 100 concurrent requests is consequent).

The other way is what you started, building a promise chain.

```
// arrayOfCompanyNames - contains an Array of [Array of Company Names] appearing in a row. Please Refer Screenshot.
var arrayOfCompanyNames;

// Function where we are traversing the company Name and making call
function getCompanyLogos(arrayOfCompanyNames) {
    // this is enough to create a 'base' resolved promise
    var promise = Promise.resolve();

    arrayOfCompanyNames.forEach(function (item) {
        item.forEach(function (value, index) {
            if (index == item.length - 1) {
                // When a row is complete then move to the next row.
                promise = promise.then(LogoFetchPromis.bind(null, value, true));
            } else {
                promise = promise.then(LogoFetchPromis.bind(null, value));
            }
        });
    });

    return promise;
}

function LogoFetchPromis(carName, wrapNow) {
    // don't create a new Promise here, $.ajax is already a promise
    return $.ajax({
        url: "/getLogo/" + carName,
        dataType: 'text'
    }).done(function (response) {
        // logos is the section where logos should appear
        $('.logos').append(response);
        if (wrapNow)
            $('.logos').append('<br>');
    }).fail(function (response) {
        // manage error here is needed
    });
}
```

I commented the changes but the most important is `promise.then(LogoFetchPromis(value));`. You're calling `LogoFetchPromis()` directly, that's why your logos show randomly, all the $.ajax are actually done at once. In the fixed code (`promise.then(LogoFetchPromis.bind(null, value)`), bind() returns a Function that is not executed until `promise` is resolved so `LogoFetchPromis()` will be called one at a time and your logos should be displayed in order.

Comment: Hi ShanShan, Thanks for your suggestion. I am going to implement it now and let you know the issue i am facing.
Just wish to know that LogoFetchPromis(carName, wrapNow), i should remove the resolve and reject calls?

Comment: Ah yes, I missed them, `resolve/reject` are no longer necessary. I'm editing my anwser.